# Access Database class through a fragment in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-fragments, fragment

I'm trying to access a SQLite Database from a fragment in my "MainActivity.java" but my Database function are in another file "Database.java" so the database_fragment.xml called in the  "onCreateView" of the "MainActivity" can't access those function... Should I just put all those database function directly into the fragment class so it could see those?

Here's the important part of my code:

(IN MainActivity.java)

```
/**
 * "fragment_database", shows the database list
 */
public static class subFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_MENU_NUMBER = "menu_number"; // Which sub-menu

    public subFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_MENU_NUMBER);
        View rootView;
        if(i==0){
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_database, container, false);
        }else{
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_help, container, false);  
        }

        return rootView;
    }


}
```

Here is the function that the XML can't reach:

(IN Database.java)

```
    public void onClick_DisplayRecords(View v) {
    displayText("Clicked display record!");

    Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();
    displayRecordSet(cursor);
}
```

The error message:

> **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onClick_DisplayRecords(View) in the activity class com.mtl.android.spca.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btnDisplay'**

Answer (score 2):

Databases are a good case for a Singleton.

```
private static SomeDatabase instance=null

private SomeDatabase(Context context) {
....
}

public static SomeDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance==null) {
        instance=new SomeDatabase(context);
    }
    return instance
}
```

Then you can use it anywhere you want to, just simply call `SomeDatabase.getInstance(context);`.

However, that's not your problem. Your problem is that you are specifying an `android:onClick` in XML, and trying to reference the callback in a Fragment. The callbacks only go to the Activity. You'll need to do something like this in your java code, basically specify the `OnClickListener` manually.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    findViewById(R.id.button_id).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick() {
             nClick_DisplayRecords()
        }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Should I add this line in the onCreateView of MainActivity then? Because it is suppose to return a view... The xml will be able to see it even though it's not from the calling class? Thx

Comment: Not knowing what your program is supposed to do, I can't answer that question. But in general, if it has to do with the fragment, it should stay in the fragment, otherwise it's okay to put it into the activity.

Comment: It's a very simple app that is suppose to show a database in the correct choosen fragment... But the thing is, all my function related to the database are in an external Database.java, it's bad if I have to redirect all those function from the MainActivity.java to the Databse.java since the xml can only access the activity...

Comment: Sounds like you want to put the code in the fragment then. Good luck!

Comment: I'll try what you said since I'm very beginner...Thank you